# Need help with Internet Explorer and jQuery AJAX using jmpopups

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, query-string

I have a calendar that uses jQuery and jmpopups to pull Event Details into a new layer. This works perfectly well in everything except Internet Explorer. IE opens an empty layer.

Here is a static version of the page:
[Calendar Debug](http://www.goodecompany.com/cal-debug.html)

Using the Firebug console, I'm using the following jQuery to test

```
$.openPopupLayer({
    name: "eventDetails",
    width: 800,
    url: "/calendar-tests/calendar-detail.html",
    cache: true,
    parameters: {details: 116}
 });
```

It works.

In IE, however, it does not load any content into the layer div. The resulting html looks like this in IE

```
<div id="popupLayer_eventDetails" style="visibility: visible; width: 800px; position: absolute; z-index: 1002; left: 210px; top: 99px;" jQuery1300126101208="86" />
```

All of the inner HTML is missing and I have no idea what the jQuery1300... in the div tag is.

Can anybody take a look at the page or point me in a direction that might get me moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... complete miss on my part. The entire problem was caused by an unmatched closing div tag in the html template used to build the layer. Bad HTML in = Nothing out. Unfortunately, Firefox and Safari were smart enough to realize my stupidity and ignore it.